# Applying Linear Gradient to a Ionic List

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I need to apply linear gradient for a list.
I am not able to do it for the entire list.
Here is a codepen example-[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/mqolp)

i tried setting background as red but its not working.

```
<ion-list style="background:red">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply styles to the generated ionic classes. You will also need to override the child item's background color to be transparent for the parent background to be seen.

```
.list {
  background: #6990E4; /* Replace with linear-gradient */
}

.list .item {
  background-color: transparent; /* To view the above background */
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/yYKpOB)